# Online drag-and-drop HTML5 IDE

Tags: javascript, css, html, ide

Today, I've thought of the following idea:

An in-browser IDE, which allows you to, on a custom viewport size, drag-and-drop HTML elements, edit their attributes, and directly (real-time) style them using CSS (by adding/editing tag-based, class-based or ID-based rules).

Overall, similar to the **Chrome debugger**, oriented towards developing webapps.
In summation, features I am looking for:

- Client-side web **app** development oriented
- Live previews
- CSS editing, similar to the Chrome debugger

I'm almost certain that something like this exists, but I could not find it after numerous Google searches. Does anyone know such a project?

Comment: Dreamweaver (a desktop app) can do this, but it generates _hideous_ code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, plenty, search web-based IDE: 
http://www.coderun.com/ide/
There is also:
http://ecco.sourceforge.net/
This is also popular:
http://shiftedit.net/

Comment: They seem to be server-side oriented and lacking real-time previews.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ Vote up would be appreciated.

Comment: None of these options have drag and drop functionality.  They are all essentially code editors.